# Calories burn rate calculation -- scientific studies

Tags: calories, calculation, met

There are many online calculators for measuring walking/running/bicycling calories burn rate. They differ in input parameters like some might need my weight as well as height and some don't. Almost none take into account duration of the exercise (and this is crucial in my opinion).

So my question here is: Where are these formulas (used in these calculators) coming from? Any scientific studies perhaps? Are they reliable?

Also I would like to know what is the most accurate method available for measuring the burn rate (I'm only interested in the scientific part, not going to do this myself).

Comment: related: [Is it possible to measure calorie burn from heart rate alone?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/is-it-possible-to-measure-calorie-burn-from-heart-rate-alone?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most accurate method is direct calorimetry. This is basically a measurement (usually for 24 hours) of the heat produced by the human body. This is usually done in a sealed chamber to fully capture all heat produced.

Next up is indirect calorimetry, where the amount of oxygen consumed and CO2 produced is directly measured, which you can then use to get calories burned.

The other equations that can estimate calorie burn as as follows (For the major ones, there are other minor ones available):

- Harris-Benedict (Original)
- Harris-Benedict (Revised)
- Cunningham
- Katch-McArdle
- Mifflin St Jeour

These were derived using testing and direct measurements to come up with broad based formulae. While probably not 100% accurate for everyone, they come pretty close. Most of your calorie burn calculators in various treadmills, etc., rely on one of these equations as their base.

The formulae themselves are backed by a lot of research and refinement, however because no two people are alike, they may over or under represent calories burned on an individual basis.

Personally, I like the Katch-McArdle, with the Mifflin equation being nearly equal.

These represent BMR (Basal Metabolic Rate) which accounts for 60-70% of the calories burned in a day. The other values for exercise have been usually pulled from a table, of which there are a few available. These are also somewhat generic, but they have been collated by using indirect calorimetry of individuals during various exercise bouts. So while they are general (like the BMR equations) they have been derived from direct sampling.